# BINARY SEARCH KEYWORD ARABIC

Tags: php, laravel, binary-search, arabic

```
$regex  = "/^{$value}/i"; 
$result = [];
if($last < 0) return [];
$data_array['binary-search'] = [];
if (preg_match('/^[\s\n]/', $value) || $value == null){
return $result;
}
if (preg_match($regex, $this->search_middle_filter($array, $middle)))
    {
        $data_array['binary-search']['result'][] = true;
        $first_result_index                    = $this->get_first_result($array, $regex, $first, $middle, $last);
        $last_result_index                     = $this->get_last_result($array, $regex, $first, $middle, $last);
        $result                                = array_merge(range($first_result_index, $last_result_index));
        $data_array['binary-search']['length']   = $result;
      
        return $result;
        
    }
```

> why the above source code can't be used to search Arabic text? how to handle it?

Comment: try `$regex  = "/^{$value}/ui"; `

Comment: Maybe it depends on your character encoding? What if you match on Unicode?